# Mass creation of folders

Tags: batch-file

I'm very fond of listening to my music and I've recently found a need to organize my folders. I have my Music folder and inside it, I have folders in the format Genre\Artist\Album. I want to create a Favorites folder for every sub-folder in the Music folder, but I already have some Favorites folders created so:

I'm trying to create a batch script that adds a Favorites folder to every sub-folder with the exception of Favorites and Discography Info folders.

I know that something along the lines of this:

```
for /r "%windir%\Users\%username%\My Music" %%s in (.) do md "Favorites" "%%s"
```

...must be used but I don't know the necessary commands to create folders in multiple folders.

How do I create exceptions in the mass folder-creating process?
How do I extend the range of the command above?

Comment: If you asked me, it would be easier to accomplish if you used a program such as Foobar to do that instead.

Comment: I'd prefer the method I'm asking for so that I can put the script into Start-up to automate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%windir%\Users\%username%\My Music"

    for /r "%root%" %%s in (.) do if not exist "%%~fs\Favorites" (
        if /i not "%%~nxs"=="Discography" if /i not "%%~nxs"=="Favorites" (
            if /i not "%%~fs"=="%root%" echo md "%%~fs\Favorites"
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

Adapt as needed. When output to console is correct, remove the `echo` command before `md` to create the directories

Comment: @user3093536: See `for /?` for a complete reference. In this case, `for` variable is `%%s`, and gets a reference to each folder in the tree. `%%~nxs` are the name and extension of the folder in `%%s`. `%%~fs` is the full path to the directory in `%%s`

Answer (score 0):

My batch scripting is a bit rusty but you can filter out strings using the `findstr` command.  Depending on your needs, this should be good enough.  It will add the folder to and path that doesn't contain the words `Favorites` or `Discography`:

```
set targetdir="%windir%\Users\%username%\My Music"
dir %targetdir% /ad /b /s > %temp%\@contents.txt
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('findstr /i /v "\<Favorites\> \<Discography\>" "%temp%\@contents.txt"') do md %%d\Favorites
```

Comment: @user3093536 and why not? `doesn't seem to work` is not really useful.

Comment: I execute this script and it doesn't create the folders; I don't exactly know how to find what the problem is in it

Comment: @user3093536: How are you running it?  Does the account you're using to run it have permissions to create the directories?  To verify the directories that would be created, replace the `md` command with `echo` and see if those are the directories you need. You'll need to try harder than that to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=c:\destdir"
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('dir /b /s /ad "%targetdir%"') do SET tdir=%%s\&CALL :test&IF DEFINED tdir ECHO md "%%s\Favorites"
GOTO :EOF
:test
SET $test=%tdir:\Discography\=%
SET $test=%$test:\Favorites\=%
IF NOT "%tdir%"=="%$test%" SET "tdir="
GOTO :eof
```

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. After you've verified that the commands are correct, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories.

Note that when an attempt is made to create a directory that already exists, an error message will be displayed. This is harmless but ugly. You can cause the error message to be suppressed by appending `2>nul` to each `MD ...` line.